# How can I determine if I have sufficient light for kohleria?

Tags: indoors, sunlight, tropical, office-gardening, african-violets

I want to grow some [kohleria](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kohleria), not sure which variety, in the office, but I am not sure the light requirement is satisfied.

Most websites said kohleria require partial shade sunlight. We don't have direct sunlight in our office:

- In our pantry, we have indirect sunlight from the East through the glass wall and the default fluorescent tubes.
- In the main office, there are only the default fluorescent tubes.

I don't have a light meter here so I don't know how to judge their light intensity. But there are some clues. I've seen my colleagues growing Gloxinia, ([Florists' Gloxinia, Sinningia speciosa](http://www.clemson.edu/extension/hgic/plants/indoor/flowering/hgic1559.html), the big flower one), and [African Violets](http://avsa.org/learning), in the office. In the main office they usually grow African Violets only and they blossom nicely. In the pantry they grow Gloxinia and African Violet. The Gloxinias grow well and blossom nicely (I know they give them fertilizer once a week to boost the flowers), but the African Violets usually don't look good and their leaves are curly.

What do you think?

Answer (score 5):

They need bright light, but cannot tolerate hot sun. Because you have no sun, that won't be a problem. Because you have fluorescent lighting bright enough to light an office, you can grow a kohleria. It would be best to grow them as close to the light as possible. On the desk is better than on the floor, and a filing cabinet is better than the desk. That is, unless you have a desk light. A desk light plus the ceiling will keep it well lit.

Comment: I think regular office light will sustain them but not be sufficient for a stunning display of flowers.